# How can I get branch name in semantic-release?

Tags: semantic-release

I am trying to create semantic releases with a tag format which includes the branch name. The `.releaserc` file looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Inder Semantic Release",
    "version": "2.1.0",
    "plugins": [
        "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
        "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
    ],
    "tagFormat": "${want_branch_name_here}-${version}",
    "branches": ['+([0-9])?(.{+([0-9]),x}).x', 'master', 'next', 'next-major', {name: 'beta', prerelease: true}, {name: 'alpha', prerelease: true}, {name: 'gpu', prerelease: true}, {name: 'non-root'}]    
}
```

I will want to get the branch name in the tag format automatically (i.e. replace `${want_branch_name_here}` with the required var that will have the value of branch name), is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Per https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/usage/configuration#tagformat - _"The tag name ... will be compiled with the `version` variable."_ This implies that no other variables will be available.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your response, i understand that it must contain a value for the version but we can still pass on other variables, i.e. some we create or the others that already exist, I am trying to get hold of something around that. I mean I can create a tag like `master-${version}` manually

Comment: *"we can still pass on other variables"* - I'm not sure what makes you think that, that's not what the linked documentation suggests.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry I missed that u think using `semantic-release/exec` to run a pre cmd or something can help ? example [here](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/support/faq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving tags while executing command `semantic-release` rather than defining tagFormat in releaserc

```
npx semantic-release -t v\${version}-$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Gives you a version like v1.0.2-master